# Relación múltiple entre dos tablas

Tags: sql, modelorelacional

Teniendo estas dos entidades

Usuarios: (IdUsuario, Nombre),
Películas: (IdPelicula, Titulo, Año)

Quisiera guardar información referente a las películas que ha reproducido un usuario y también cuales ha añadido como favoritas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Seria correcto usar una doble relación entre tablas? Esto me genera por un lado una nueva tabla donde guardar las películas reproducidas del usuario y otra las que ha guardado en favoritos.

Comment: Si continúas con esa lógica, tendrás **una tabla nueva por cada tipo de relación** entre películas y usuarios. Qué tal las películas que el usuario dejó a medias? Qué tal las películas que usuarios dio like, las que le dio dislike. Las películas que usuario metió a la lista *"ver después"*. Yo crearía una tabla `TipoRelación`, con todos esos detalles y una tabla `UsuarioPelicula` que guarde `IdUsuario`, `IdPelicula`, `IdTipoRelacion`. A como está escrita la pregunta, hay N respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relación muchos a muchos

Una relación muchos a muchos se produce cuando tenemos dos tablas, *tabla1* y *tabla2* por ejemplo, y los registros de *tabla1* se asocian a multiples registros de la *tabla2* y, a su vez, los registros de la *tabla2* se asocian con multiples registros de la *tabla1*.

Para llevar a cabo estas relaciones se hace uso de una tercer tabla auxiliar donde la relación de *tabla1* y *tabla2* será de uno a muchos con respecto a esta.
Los datos que debe tener esta tabla son:

- El `id` primario de la tabla auxiliar
- El `id` primario de la tabla1
- El `id` primario de la tabla2

| id | tabla1_id | tabla2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 20 | 1 |

Es muy recomendable que los `id` primarios de las *tabla1* y *tabla2* en la tabla auxiliar se configuren como `llaves externas`.

Answer (score 1):

Pues no te queda otra opción que crear tantas relaciones cómo necesites para modelar tu problema. Supongo que se te hará extraño que dos entidades se relacionen por dos caminos diferentes, pero es algo totalmente normal. La semántica lo justifica. No te preocupes por el bucle, en este caso no generas ningún tipo de redundancia.

Recuerda que en el modelo E-R hablamos de entidades. Cuando implementemos físicamente la base de datos serán tablas pero, de momento, aún no las llamamos así.